# OpenCV : Building a simple 3d model

Tags: opencv, 3d

I Have decided to use OpenCV to build a 3d scene by using a series of 2D Images. I found the example code that came with OpenCV [ build3dmodel.cpp [Here](https://code.ros.org/trac/opencv/browser/trunk/opencv/samples/cpp/build3dmodel.cpp?rev=3220) ].

I just want to run this once and see what kind of outcome this gives. My knowledge with OpenCV is low, I don't want to understand the whole code, I just want to know how to give inputs to this program (the image set) to see the output.

Answer (score 1):

The line command of this code example requires the following parameters:

> build3dmodel -i intrinsics_filename.yml [-d detector] [-de
>   descriptor_extractor] -m model_name.yml

The first file is the camera matrix which you obtain after the calibration process (there is an especific example with it). Detector and descriptor detector must match with valid FeatureDetector and DescriptorExtractor names. Model name is a bit confusing, it looks like part of the yml file name where data will be saved.

Answer (score -1):

First see some tutorial like [introduction to OpenCv](http://www.cs.iit.edu/~agam/cs512/lect-notes/opencv-intro/opencv-intro.html) or [OpenCV tutorial](http://dasl.mem.drexel.edu/~noahKuntz/openCVTut1.html). Also, see [input and output with OpenCv](http://www.neuroforge.co.uk/index.php/input-and-output-with-open-cv).

Comment: I am aware of the basic codes , but can you point out where and how the inputs should be given in the code i have linked ?